# How to take a word from a file, and store it in a variable? C++

Tags: c++, string, variables

I have made a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game in C++ Console Application. The game so far, worked great.. until I tried storing a word from a file, inside a variable, and then trying to use that variable in IF statements.

---

Here's how I store my word from the file, in a variable.

```
string comp_selection;
char player_selection;
```

And here's the part of the code where I am trying to get it to work.

```
cout << "Rock, Paper, or Scissors?";
cin >> player_selection;

if (comp_selection =='r' || comp_selection == 'R')
{
    if (player_selection == 'r' || player_selection == 'R')
    {
        cout << "Computer chose " << comp_selection << "... It's a draw!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (player_selection == 'p' || player_selection == 'P')
    {
        cout << "Computer chose " << comp_selection << "... You win!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (player_selection == 's' || player_selection == 'S')
    {
        cout << "Computer chose " << comp_selection << "... You lose!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output should be:

> Computer chose Rock... You win!

If the player chose Paper for example.
Instead, I get this error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Any help or guidance, would be great! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: see the error !!  no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' .. you are comparing char with std::string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `comp_selection` is defined as a `std::string`, but you are comparing it against a `char` (`'r'`, etc). You should compare it against another string (`"r"`) or just redefine `comp_selection` to be a character:

```
char comp_selection;
char player_selection;
```

In C++, a single character is denoted by single quotes (`'c'`) whereas a string of characters is denoted by double quotes (`"full string"`).

Comment: That method works great, however, when I output the message, with the char method, the output simply reads the first letter of the string, and not the whole string. I'd like the whole string to be outputted.

Answer (score 0):

So far, you have been enjoying `cin >>` overloading recognizing that it's writing to a `char`.  When reading from a file, you've apparently utilized a string.  This is fine, except now the compiler is complaining that it does not know how to compare a `string` and a `char`.  In short, your types don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare only first character of comp_selection (comp_selection[0])

```
if (comp_selection[0] =='r' || comp_selection[0] == 'R')
{
```

It is not the best solution but it requires the minimum code changes...

Answer (score -1):

I've just realised that my code does what it was intended to do! By setting my 
`comp_selection` to `char`, like someone here suggested, I can manually input what the computer chose by using the IF Statements.

For example:

```
if (comp_selection == 's' || comp_selection == 'S')
{
    if (player_selection == 'r' || player_selection == 'R')
    {
        cout << "Computer chose Scissors... You win!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (player_selection == 'p' || player_selection == 'P')
    {
        cout << "Computer chose Scissors... You lose!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (player_selection == 's' || player_selection == 'S')
    {
        cout << "Computer chose Scissors... It's a draw!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```